# Multiple calendar ID's in a google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

New to programming and I have been hitting my head against the wall when trying to add multiple calendar ID's to the script below. 
I need it to iterate through the rows and if the event hasn't been added to the calendar yet, add it to mine and to others' calendars, as the sheet gets updated.

```
function addToCal() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ProductionSchedule"),
      range = sheet.getActiveRange(),
      row = range.getRow(),
      data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 26).getValues(),
      date = data[0][6];
  if (date =='') return;
  var today = new Date(),
      startDate = new Date(today.setMonth(today.getMonth()-1)),
      endDate = new Date(today.setMonth(today.getMonth()+6)),
      calId = 'calendarID',
      cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId),
      events = cal.getEvents(startDate, endDate),
      titles = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = events.length; i < len; i++)
    titles.push(events[i].getTitle());
  var item = ('Produção de' + ' ' + data[0][3]),
      qtd = ('Qtd (und): ' + data[0][5]),
      local = ('Local de Produção: ' + data[0][4]);
  var index = titles.indexOf(item),
      ok = 1;
  if (index > -1)
  {
    var eventDate = events[index].getAllDayStartDate();
    if (eventDate.getTime() == date.getTime()) var ok = 0;
    else events[index].deleteEvent();
  }
  if (ok) 
    cal.createAllDayEvent(item, date, {description: qtd, location: local})
    .removeAllReminders();
}
```

Currently, it sets the events to my calendar containing Item Description as the event title, Product name, qty and  Production Location in the description field. I would need the same information to be added to others' calendars.

Besides, this can't mark me as Busy and the event doesn't need to be an All Day event.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers,

Comment: Can you talk about the current result and the expected result? it's not clair what is wrong with only this code

Comment: Just did, @LioraHaydont. Thanks!

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking for. Are you saying you want execute `cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId)` and the following calendar interaction multiple times, each with a different calendar ID?

Comment: @chuckx I just added a bit more information to the post above. I still need to adjust my mindset to be able to put my question thoroughly. Working on it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to repeat the calendar interactions for multiple calendars, you need to create an array of calendar IDs and loop through them.

One approach would be:

```
var CALENDER_IDS = [
  "calendarID1",
  "calendarID2",
  "calendarID3",
]

func addToCal() {

  ... spreadsheet data extraction and date calculations ...

  for (var i = 0, clen = CALENDER_IDS.length; i < clen; i++) {
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CALENDER_IDS[i]);

    ... calendar interactions ...
  }
}
```

If you use the above code, make sure to update the counter variable in the title loop (i.e. they both can't be `i`). [Common practice is to make inner loops use `j`, `k`, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Loop_counters)